# Adding site collection to Web Application logged in as FBA in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Hi 
I am trying to create Site collection under web application which is configured as Claim based authentication and the code is as follow:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate {
  using (SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site)
  {
    using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
    {
      site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
      web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
      try
      {
        SPWebApplication web_App = web.Site.WebApplication;
        web_App.Sites.Add(SiteUrl, SiteTitle, Description, Convert.ToUInt32(Constants.LOCALE_ID_ENGLISH), SiteTemplate, OwnerLogin, "testuser", OwnerEmail);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      { 
        string s = ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace;
        throw;
      }
      finally
      {
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here I am passing "OwnerLogin" as "CustomMembership:UserName". But web_App.Sites.Add is throwing a wierd error like "ex = {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}". Any help in this regard is really appreciated.
Regards,
Paddy

Comment: I don't think that's the root of the problem here, but you should not dispose `SPSite` object returned by the `SPContext.Current.Site` property (i.e. remove the 1st `using`) - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx#SPDisposeCheckID_220

Comment: Its called from a aspx page which is in _layouts folder. Paddy

Answer (score 1):

Your elevation code is wrong, you need to create completely new SPSite and SPWeb references. I normal prefix them with "c" to show me that it is in a different context.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
    using (SPSite csite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID)) {
        using (SPWeb cweb = csite.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.ID)) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `OwnerLogin` parameter should **not** contain the *CustomMembership:* prefix - pass plain *UserName* as a value of this parameter.

---

By the way, your method of getting the Web Application object is unnecessarily complicated - use something like this:

```
SPWebApplication webApplication = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new System.Uri("Web-Application-URL"));
```

Comment: Thanks Marek for those tips. But the issue still persists. I followed all the suggestion made on this Questions but none is working-out for me. Still trying to get hold of a solution.

Comment: @Paddy (1) This thread http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/51ad553a-ec7b-46b6-873c-d49b2544c55f/ contains a detailed discussion of a similar problem - it may give you some ideas. (2) Did you consider using the Administration Web service http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcadmin.admin.createsite.aspx? I am using a Web service to create site collections under FBA Web Application and it's working fine.

Comment: @Paddy After doing some more research and testing, I am beginning to think that **it is not possible to create a new site collection directly from an `.aspx` page placed in `_layouts` folder**. It probably requires some privileges that site collection users (FBA or not, it doesn't matter) don't have - farm administrator maybe? In my opinion, you have to either use the built-in Administration Web service or create a custom one (remember it must be deployed to the `ADMISAPI` folder).